# Apply margin to running CSS position

Tags: itext, footer, css

I'm using the following CSS code to position my footer at the bottom of the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        @bottom-center { content: element(footer); }
    }
    #footer {position: running(footer);}
</style>
```

Is there a way to display it slightly higher? Adding `margin-bottom: 50px` doesn't seem to have an effect.

update: the page will be converted to PDF using iText

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working with the following CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
      @page { 
          margin-bottom: 100px;
          @bottom-center { 
            content:element(footer);
          }
      }

    #footer {
      position: running(footer);
    }
</style>
```

Previously, I only tried to add margin-bottom to the @bottom-center and #footer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you usually use:

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjBJs/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that way it doesn't render correctly when I export to PDF (iText).

Comment: This is a print question and the author provides plenty of examples to clarify as much